# Disable or change Reporting in TFS 2013 when configured server missing/offline

Tags: tfs

Like many other out there I had the fun task of upgrading or TFS 2008 server to a brand-new TFS 2013 install.

The good news -> this has been done and documented.  The bad news -> you have to migrate to TFS 2012 and then Migrate from 2012 to 2013.

All things said it mostly went fairly smooth.  I cannot really complain.  There is one hitch, however.  Or plan was to use an intermediate server (SQLTFS01) for the TFS and SQL Server 2012 install and then most everything onto our destination server for 2013 (SQL008).  Then we were to take SQLTFS01 offline and re purpose that machine.

In the end there was a missed step.  It seems that our final install of TFS2013 is still pointed to SQLTFS01 for the reporting services components.  See here:

[image]

Attempts to disable the reporting and analysis services portion of the server are all failing because even in order to disable the tool, it tries to connect to the existing tool.

Question:  How can we disable this feature or redirect this stuff?  Can we do it though setting files that I am not aware of?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Dumb question: What happens when you click Edit and change the server names?

Comment: As described, when I try to change the servers in "Edit" then it seems to first try to connect to the existing server before the changeover.  On that part of the process, it fails and will not continue on.  I have tried that variation on all three tabs in the popup.  Even opening edit and closing without changes will also cause an error.  I know all these settings are in XML somewhere, so I am wondering of anyone knows how to change all these things within config files somewhere, or through PowerShell

Comment: Can you share the error? The setting are not in XML and are stored in the TFS DB...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you "unconfigure" your application tier by running "tfsconfig setup /uninstall:all". This will nit touch any of your data but will reset your app tier to the state before you ran the configuration.

You can then follow the steps in the "move to new hardware" documentation so that you don't miss any of the steps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx

If you start from after "restore databases" step you should be good.